# signal SIGFPE using cpp-httplib

Tags: c++, http, gdb, httplib

I'm using httplib in a program.After a while some error happen and the program will shutdown.
gdb gives these :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0Yon.png)

I wonder what cause this error and How can I fix this?

Comment: It's most likely caused by a bug in your own code.

Comment: Recompile your code with debug symbols so you can at least see which of your handlers (and which line inside it) goes wrong? And, while you're at it, share the code of said handler.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.